# Saving mysql data in binary

Tags: php, mysql, binary

Is there a way I could retrieve data from a mysql db table and save them in a binary file?

My table looks like this

```
id  domain_name  isAuth
1   www.yah.com  1
2   www.go.com   0
3   www.goo.com  1
4   www.foo.com  1
```

Comment: i have been using writing to a file(fwrite) and reading(fread) from concept for one of my jobs.. it seems a bit time consuming, so i saw a suggestion in the internet to use a binary file.. no technical information.. put it on stack to get a head start with some help from programming expeerts

Comment: It depends on what you want to do with the data after saving it to a file.

Comment: cant you guys give me a simple example of doing above or anything related to above

Comment: **No**. Your question is vague and incomplete, and thus cannot be answered. I can give you a hundred examples of "writing data to a file", but then you just have a file that contains data you can't read. In that case it's better not to create the file in the first place. So, again: **What do you want with that file?** Do you want to read it again in PHP? Do you want to send it over the internet? Do you want to be able to restore your database from it?

Comment: thanks for the explanation, what i want to do is, get the table data into binary format and read it again using php..

Answer (score 1):

Since performance seems to be the issue here, assuming `$data` is the result of a call to [`PDOStatement::fetchAll`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) or [`mysqli_fetch_all`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php), I suggest [`serialize`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) and [`unserialize`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php):

```
/* fetch $data */
file_put_contents('my_file.dat', serialize($data));
/* do some other stuff */
$data = unserialize(file_get_contents('my_file.dat'));
/* use $data */
```

Comment: @SoththiUpali With `pack` you could write actual binary data, thus creating a much denser file. In a language with reasonable performance (like C or Java) you would normally do this because it has better performance than anything else and the resulting file is no larger than needed. However, writing a function in PHP that iterates over an array and `pack`s it is most likely a lot slower than using a built-in function like `serialize`, which is written in C.